# Why won't code run properly in c++

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{

    std::cout << " Here is my calculator!\n ";
    int input;
    std::cout << " What operation do you wish to use? Use +, -, x, / as signs!\n ";
    std::cin >> input;
    std::cin.ignore();
    if ( input == "+" )
 {
    int no1;
    std::cout << " Okay, addition what is your first number? ";
    std::cin >> no1;
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cout << " Okay, So your first number is " << no1 << "!\n";
    int no2;
    std::cout << " So you're first number is " << no1 << " What do you wish you're second number to be? " << "!\n";
    std::cin >> no2;
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cout << " Okay so you're second number is " << no2 << "In the end the equation is " << no1 << "+" << no2 << "!\n";
    std::cout << " The answer to you're question is " << no1 << "+" << no2 << "=" << no2 + no1 << "!\n";
    std::cout << " Thank you for using my calculator, Bye!\n";

}
```

The runner says that there is a problem on line 9, the one with the if statement. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Post the exact error. A broad paraphrase of it isn't very helpful.

Comment: And you're trying to compare a string an an int. I don't think c++ allows that. You should take the input as a string if you expect to use a string.

Comment: You should change `int input;` to `char input;` and of course change `if ( input == "+" )` to `if ( input == '+' )`.

Comment: The „runner“ is a compiler.

Answer (score 2):

On line 5 you are declaring input as an `int`. On line 9 you're comparing input (the integer) to a `string`, which is not possible. If you would change `"+"` to `'+'`, the check would work. 
Changing input to be a `char` and change the condition to `if (input == '+')` would be better though (as said by [DimChtz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6084430/dimchtz)).